# Get background color from an image using color-thief

Tags: javascript, image, background, rgb

I am working on a script to grab the dominant color from an image using color-thief.js and then use that color as background-color. I have never used this plugin before so I don't know what I am exactly doing wrong. The background color is not applying though.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".box img").load(function(){
        var dominantColor = getDominantColor($(this));
        $(this).parent().css("background-color", "rgb("+dominantColor+")");
    });        
});
```

Thanks in advcance.

Comment: `console.log(dominantColor);` << what is the output

Comment: ReferenceError: getDominantColor is not defined Thats what the console returns. Might it be a problem in my linking?

Comment: you're not referencing ColorThief() object first.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initiate the ColorThief object to reference its internal methods.

```
var colorThief = new ColorThief();
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".box img").load(function(){
         var dominantColor = colorThief.getColor($(this));
         console.log(dominantColor);
         $(this).parent().css("background-color", "rgb("+dominantColor+")");
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help already. I mover the first line inseide the function and now the console has no errors but its still not working.

Comment: The console sometimes includes an error message ReferenceError: getDominantColor is not defined. However, I don't understand why it would.

Comment: @Fyxerz - You are not following XaxD's code. If you have used his code you wouldn't get that error. (Because then it would say the property is not defined instead of a reference error if it was actually not defined)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I literraly copied and pasted his code. There must be something else I'm doing wrong. I am a complete nob with jQuery too. Im sorry about my lack of ability with it.

Comment: I have the problem with the code, I had a different version that the one that the code was written. Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: The problem was that the files I downloaded do not correspond with the documentation given on the site. It shouldn't be .getDominantColor(); but .getColor(sourceImage);